# iOS - Memory usage doubles after presenting ViewController due to ImageIO_PNG_Data

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks

**EDIT**:
I have now found the root of the issue thanks to the Instrumenting tool on Mac.
[image]
When I show the ViewController, there is one instance of ImageIO that takes 242.7MB memory space. I have checked and this corresponds exactly to the massive jump. I have been unable to find what this image is as I have no image of this size or anywhere near this size in the project. Does anyone have an idea how I can pinpoint the issue further?

I'm trying to debug the memory usage of my iOS app. Here is the current scenario:
-memory usage after launch is around 250mb
-when I open one specific ViewController, memory goes up to about 580mb
This action causes a major lag in the app, i.e it takes a visible moment to present the ViewController.

I am now trying to use XCode's memory profiling tools to find out what is taking up so much memory. I've found a couple of weird things:
-when checking the memory graph hierarchy, I initially have 224 objects
-when I launch the ViewController, this goes up to 227 objects (only 3 more objects, which are the ViewController itself, one CustomScrollView, and another Google Analytics object)
-when I dismiss the view, the object count goes back to 224, but the memory usage only decreases to about 550mb (so some memory is leaking, but I don't see where it is).

When I re-open another instance of the same problematic ViewController afterwards, there is no lag, and it opens instantly.

Is there anything that I'm missing here that could explain these weird memory fluctuations? Thank you so much.

*EDIT*:
This is how I present the ViewController:

```
            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"AutoLayoutStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        ShowViewController *sfvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ShowView"];
        sfvc.idEvent = idEvenement;
        sfvc.usesGivenData = TRUE;
        sfvc.event = (I_Event *)[[self getCorrectArrayForSection:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:sfvc animated:YES];
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

This is the log that appears when I present the ViewController:

```
2019-01-31 11:23:12.838140-0500 app[52956:9348407] [INFO] {}[General]: GPU Identifier: Apple Software Renderer
2019-01-31 11:23:14.692535-0500 app[52956:9349579] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C21.1:2][0x7fd6f1804a10] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-01-31 11:23:14.692879-0500 app[52956:9349579] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C21.1:2][0x7fd6f1804a10] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-01-31 11:23:14.693309-0500 app[52956:9349579] TIC Read Status [21:0x0]: 1:57
2019-01-31 11:23:14.693536-0500 app[52956:9349579] TIC Read Status [21:0x0]: 1:57
2019-01-31 11:23:14.695037-0500 app[52956:9349579] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C20.1:2][0x7fd6f0e37780] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-01-31 11:23:14.695215-0500 app[52956:9349579] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C20.1:2][0x7fd6f0e37780] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-01-31 11:23:14.695574-0500 app[52956:9349579] TIC Read Status [20:0x0]: 1:57
2019-01-31 11:23:14.695670-0500 app[52956:9349579] TIC Read Status [20:0x0]: 1:57
2019-01-31 11:23:14.912936-0500 app[52956:9349564] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C25.1:2][0x7fd6ee5d8710] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-01-31 11:23:14.913128-0500 app[52956:9349564] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C25.1:2][0x7fd6ee5d8710] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-01-31 11:23:14.913838-0500 app[52956:9349564] TIC Read Status [25:0x0]: 1:57
2019-01-31 11:23:14.914180-0500 app[52956:9349564] TIC Read Status [25:0x0]: 1:57
```

And some extra information: I tried completing commenting out ALL code in the ViewController.m file, and the memory still goes up as high. The ViewController is a heavy/complex view in Storyboard, with a big ScrollView, but could this alone explain this jump in memory usage?

This is what the profiler looks like. The big bump you see on the blue graph on top is when I open the specific ViewController. It seems like the Anonymous VM memory usage is completely out of control, and the ImageIO_PNG_Data. Is there anything I can do on that side?
[image]

Comment: can you post the code how you are presenting the ViewController?

Comment: I just added some code, the logs and some context! Thanks a lot!

Comment: does `getCorrectArrayForSection` generate any data and store it somewhere? like a cache?

Comment: did you check the `deinit` of the new `ViewController` to see if it was deallocated when you dismiss it?

Comment: No, that method doesn't store any data. And since the ViewController disappears of the Memory Graph Hierarchy it means it was deallocated, right?

Comment: It seems clear to me now that the issue is related to the PNG image. There is one single image that takes over 240MB of memory, but I'm incapable of finding which one. There is no image in my project that is anywhere near that big. How can I pinpoint this better? Thanks!

Comment: That sounds interesting that so much memory is used up by the PNG image. Can you post a screenshot of the memory graph? Does it point to any object?

Comment: Which part exactly could I screenshot? I'm trying to find instances of UIImage/UIImageView but there are so much it's hard

Comment: That is just plain crazy memory usage. The max texture size of 4096x4096 BGRA pixels is only 64 Megs on iOS hardware. You will need to examine the images inside your Assets folder and attached directly to the project and see where this massive image is. You can use the "file" command to quickly print the dimensions of PNG images from the command line.

Comment: What images do you display in your view (either fixed images in the storyboard or ones loaded from the net)? How many are there? What is their resolution? It looks as if you have 14 PNG images with a resolution in the order of 3000 by 2000 pixels.

Comment: Nail on the head, @Codo. This was indeed the issue. I had PNG images that weren't that, that heavy (not more than 1mb), but their resolution was extremely high (more than 3000 pixels by 3000). They ended up being resized to very small images but this completely messed up. Thanks a bunch y'all ! if you want to post something as an answer I'll gladly give you the validation ! Thanks a bunch.